# React hooks, state is not changing correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In this project I use react hooks, this snippet used to change color theme of project, but there's the problem which I can not to solve.
      const lightTheme = {
         ...
         }

```
  const darkTheme = {
     ...
  }
 export const ThemeState = ({children}) => {

  const initialState = {
     theme: lightTheme
  }

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(ActionReducer, initialState)

  const {theme} = state 

  const themeToggler = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault()
     console.log(theme)
     if(theme == lightTheme){
        dispatch({type:THEME, payload: darkTheme})
     }
     else if(theme == darkTheme){
        dispatch({type:THEME, payload: lightTheme})
     }
   }
```

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

My reducer:

```
export const ActionReducer = (state, action) => {
         switch(action.type) {
           case THEME:
             return{
               ...state,
               theme: action.payload
            }
           default:
              return state
   }
};

Here is component with toggle button by each click, I need to change theme in state, it clicks correctly:
```

```
import {ThemeContext} from '../../store/themeState'

function Main () {
  const {theme, themeToggler} = useContext(ThemeContext)
   return (
       <button onClick={e => {themeToggler(e)}}></button>
   )
}

 export default Main
```

```
 when I press the button i catch this log


    ({body: "#E2E2E2", text: "#363537"}
      {body: "#363537", text: "#FAFAFA"}
      {body: "#363537", text: "#FAFAFA"}
      ....)

I don't know why do state changes like this. If you can, help me to solve this bug.)
```

Comment: Can you add your ActionReducer and where you console.log the state?

Comment: You need to post your ActionReducer and theme reducer code so we can help you find any issues

Comment: @Domino987, I pinned my reducer

Comment: And where do you log it ;)

Comment: @Domino987 before if operator, look

Comment: Where is your onPress code to change the theme?

Comment: @Travis, in the React component, problem is not there

Comment: You are asking why you are getting the logs you posted when you press the button, so if you want us to help you then you need to post the code where you press the button

Comment: Where do you use themeToggler? Can you post that code? Also, you should move lightTheme, darkTheme, and initialState out of the component, those are redifined each render.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial theme is `body: '{#E2E2E2', text: '#363537'}`.

When you click the button, you log this theme `{body: "#E2E2E2", text: "#363537"}`, which is correctly your initial theme.

After you log it, you update the theme to be the dark theme `{body: '#363537', text: '#FAFAFA'}`.

This will be logged, once you click the button again:  `{body: "#363537", text: "#FAFAFA"}`.

Now comes the problem, since you create the darkTheme object on every render, the references are not the same as previous, so the comparison `else if(theme == darkTheme)` fails, because the darkTheme object is different from the previous darkTheme object.

Either move the theme object generation out of the component, so you do not generate a new one on every render or add a type to the theme:

```
const lightTheme = {
  body: '#E2E2E2',
  text: '#363537',
  type: "light"
}`
```

and compare those: `if(theme.type == darkTheme.type)`

Comment: Thanks, man, you are incredible, I did not now that react creates new references after render, so I just put this objects from the function and problem is solved, thank you again)))

Comment: @AlexKhanas as an alternative, please check my answer, it deserves an upvote:)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to toggle the theme on button click:

So you can do this:

ThemeState

```js
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import { TOGGLE_THEME } from "./ActionTypes";
import ActionReducer from "./ActionReducer";

const lightTheme = {
  body: "#E2E2E2",
  text: "#363537"
};

const darkTheme = {
  body: "#363537",
  text: "#FAFAFA"
};

const initialState = {
  isLightTheme: true
};

export const ThemeState = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(ActionReducer, initialState);

  const { isLightTheme } = state;

  const themeToggler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({ type: TOGGLE_THEME });
  };

  const backgroundColor = isLightTheme ? lightTheme.body : darkTheme.body;
  const fontColor = isLightTheme ? lightTheme.text : darkTheme.text;

  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: `${backgroundColor}` }}>
      <p style={{ color: `${fontColor}` }}>Some Text</p>
      <button type="submit" onClick={themeToggler}>
        Toggle Theme
      </button>
      <hr />
      Current Theme: {isLightTheme ? "light" : "dark"}
    </div>
  );
};
```

ActionReducer:

```
import { TOGGLE_THEME } from "./ActionTypes";

export default function(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_THEME:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLightTheme: !state.isLightTheme
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

ActionTypes:

```
export const TOGGLE_THEME = "TOGGLE_THEME";
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-faraday-r0m48)

Answer (score 0):

I created a minimal example on how this behavior [could be implemented](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-kare-cbsn8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark):

```js
const darkTheme = {
  color: "green"
};

const lightTheme = {
  color: "red"
};

export default function App() {
  const [useLightTheme, setUseLightTheme] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className={useLightTheme ? darkTheme.color : lightTheme.color}>
      <button onClick={() => setUseLightTheme(!useLightTheme)}>toggle</button>
      some example text
    </div>
  );
}
```

Since you did not provide all relevant code (e.g. the reducer), I can't explain your code.

Comment: I provided reducer now